# Comparando arrays en javascript

Tags: javascript

Resolví de esta manera un ejercicio que pide chequear si un array es una subsecuencia de otro array.

```
array = [5, 1, 22, 25, 6, -1, 8, 10];
subsequence = [1, 6, -1, 10];

function isValidSubsequence(array, sequence) {
  let answer = [];
  let j = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let test = sequence[j];

    if (test == array[i]) {
      answer.push(test);
      j++;
    }
  }

  if (subsequence == answer) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

isValidSubsequence(array, subsequence);
```

El array answer que uso para comprobarlo anda perfecto (ya los comparé con un console.log y son iguales). Lo que no entiendo es por qué la comparación entre ambos arrays me retorna false. Si las comparo con un solo = retorna true (entiendo que lo que compara es el tipo de dato, correcto?). Pero qué sucede cuando uso el doble o triple operador de comparación en el caso de los arrays?

PD.: Llegue al resultado esperado haciendo un JSON.stringify de ambos arreglos para compararlos como string y funciona perfecto. ¿Habría otra solución menos rebuscada?

Answer (score 0):

La comparación simple `==` y la comparación estricta `===` no nos sirve para comparar el contenido de dos arreglos, para esto, lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
array = [5, 1, 22, 25, 6, -1, 8, 10];
subsequence = [1, 6, -1, 10];

function isValidSubsequence(array, sequence) {
  let answer = [];
  let j = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let test = sequence[j];

    if (test == array[i]) {
      answer.push(test);
      j++;
    }
  }

  return sequence.every((n, i) => n == answer[i]);
}

console.log(isValidSubsequence(array, subsequence));
```

el método `every` verifica que nuestra condición sea verdadera para todos los elementos de nuestro arreglo, en este caso compara que todos los elementos de `sequence` sean iguales a los elementos de `answer`